# How to run multiple commands in cmd using a script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have three different commands that I want to execute my running one script,

I created a file called as myscript.bat

I want the following two commands to run in sequence when I run the script:

**cd C:\Users\johnDoe\Idea\View\Proxy**

**node proxy.js**

**PS:And after that I want the cmd to be left open, not close automatically**

Comment: What do you mean by `open to be left open`?

Comment: @mklement0 Sorry edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Leave the bat file as it is, but run it with `cmd /k myscript.bat`. Also, if there's a chance of the command window opening by default on another drive, you might want to add the line `C:` to the beginning of the script to change volumes. `cd` changes folders within a given volume, but it doesn't actually change volumes.

Alternatively, if you just want the window to stay open so you can read the output, but you don't actually want to run any additional commands in it after your commands finish, you can just add the line `pause` at the end of the script.

Comment: +1; simpler: use `cd`'s `/D` switch - it changes drives, if necessary.

Comment: No, you don't have to open the cmd window manually. As mklement0 pointed out, you can just make another .bat file that contains only the line `cmd /k myscript.bat` and double-click that one from explorer. It will then open a new cmd window automatically that will run myscript.bat and then stay open after it finishes.

Answer (score 1):

@reirab's answer contains the crucial pointer: use `cmd /k` to create a console window that stays open.

If you don't want to use `cmd /k` *explicitly* - say, because you want to open the batch file from Explorer, you have 2 options:

- [Suboptimal] Add a `cmd /k` statement as the *last* statement to your batch file.
- [Better] Write a *wrapper* batch file that invokes the target batch file with `cmd /k`.

For instance, if your batch file is `startProxy.bat`, create another batch file in the same folder, name it `startProxyWrapper.bat`, and assign the following content:

```
@cmd /k "%~dp0startProxy.bat"
```

When you then open `startProxyWrapper.bat` from Explorer, a persistent console window (one that stays open) will open and execute `startProxy.bat`.